# How do I align an inline-flex label vertically with the text surrounding it?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I have a label that has `display: inline-flex` alongside a span. I would like to center the label so that the middle of its text aligns properly with the rest of the text.

[Misaligned label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKOoM.png)

How could I do this? I imagine this is a common problem since labeled text is fairly common.

My code using Tailwind classes.

```
<div class="font-[400] text-[14px] leading-[23px] text-[#4A585F]">
  <span
    class="inline-flex gap-[4px] px-[4px] py-[2px] rounded-[100px] items-center bg-[#F4F5F7] h-fit w-fit mr-[12px]"
    ><img
      class="w-[16px] h-[16px] rounded-[63px] border border-solid border-black"
      src="https://img.favpng.com/1/15/9/scalable-vector-graphics-computer-icons-user-profile-portable-network-graphics-png-favpng-n05BjRqcBz9Ub9NtAbz8GXEaN.jpg"
    /><span
      class="font-[400] text-[12px] leading-[20px] text-[#4A585F] whitespace-nowrap"
      >Random Username</span
    ></span
  ><span class="mr-[36px]"
    >added a comment to <a class="text-[#2875D0]">Random Document</a> in
    <a class="text-[#2875D0]">Random Task Case</a></span
  ><span class="italic text-[12px] leading-[20px]">1 hour ago</span>
</div>
```

I've tried setting the line-height of the surrounding text but that only increased space between the lines of text. I can't set flex on the parent container as that will split the label and the rest of the text into separate sections. I tried using margin-top and padding-top but that shifted it slightly but not in the way I expected using a large range of values.

I expect the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqObV.png)

If you look carefully, the Random Username should be shifted downwards by a few pixels to be in line with the rest of the text.

Edit: I've made progress by using float-left on the label and setting the line-height of the rest of the text equal to the label text, which works for my specific use case. However, this will not work if my label is in the center of my text.

Comment: Try using the `vertical-align` property on the `inline-flex` element.

Comment: We need your css code...

Comment: try adding ``align-middle`` in 'added a comment' class

Comment: Thank you, vertical align worked! Specifically, align-top and align-bottom both centered the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `align-middle` and `mt-2` class to get the expected result.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="font-[400] text-[14px] leading-[23px] mt-2 text-[#4A585F]">
  <span
    class="inline-flex gap-[4px] align-middle  px-[4px] py-[2px] rounded-[100px] items-center bg-[#F4F5F7] h-fit w-fit mr-[12px]"
    ><img
      class="w-[16px] h-[16px] rounded-[63px] border border-solid border-black"
      src="https://img.favpng.com/1/15/9/scalable-vector-graphics-computer-icons-user-profile-portable-network-graphics-png-favpng-n05BjRqcBz9Ub9NtAbz8GXEaN.jpg"
    /><span
      class="font-[400] text-[12px]  leading-[20px] text-[#4A585F] whitespace-nowrap"
      >Random Username</span
    ></span
  ><span class="mr-[36px]"
    >added a comment to <a class="text-[#2875D0]">Random Document</a> in
    <a class="text-[#2875D0]">Random Task Case</a></span
  ><span class="italic text-[12px] leading-[20px]">1 hour ago</span>
</div>
```